# trying to avoid seemingly repetitive code

Tags: range, border

This code works as required to draw individual cell borders in a row specified by the “IntRowNo” parameter that is passed in via user input.

The range is cell B through L in IntRowNo

```vb
Sub ColorMRowCel(IntRowNo)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & IntRowNo).VerticalAlignment = xlCenter

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("I" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("J" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & IntRowNo).BorderAround LineStyle:=xlContinuous, Weight:=xlThin
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L" & IntRowNo).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & IntRowNo).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
End Sub
```

The problem is that I am not able to make it elegant and compact.  Can someone help, please?

Comment: Did you try to put the same logic inside a function that you can call in a for loop for the range you want?

Comment: You can also add parameters to that function for specifics things like `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`.

Comment: This code is already inside a sub called into play when user specifies a row number.  I want to make this code more easy to edit in future if, say, I need to include an extra column letter or modify existing borders.  Thanks.

Comment: You can just add the LetterColumn, and extra parameters to your function. Then, you will be able to call the function inside a loop. I don't know if it is what you want ? If not, can you provide more information about the flow?

Comment: I found a solution pieced togather from internet searches but it is 215 characters too long to post as a comment and am not sure how to present it.   Basically it involves using two sub routines, one to identify the column letter in the first sub and using the Select Case statement to set-up cell borders as required in the second sub.  Thank you for your comments.